# How to connect my IOS app to a chromecast that is being casted on by another device without overrwriting the current cast session

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Title, my app is supposed to function as a controller, changing volume forward/back etc, but I can't seem connect to the chromecast without overwriting the cast session that is currently going on. Is there anyway to just join the current cast session of the chromecast without interrupting and overriding it?

read the developer docs forward and backwards to try and figure it out but my app always starts a new cast session.